# using div like table

Tags: html, css

how can i make layout without using table but only div?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the `table` element because you want to satisfy accessibility guidelines? If so then be aware that simply replacing the `table`, `tr`, `td` elements with `div` elements will not solve accessibility problems. The reason that a table is inaccessible is that a text-reader will have to work harder to make your page understandable for someone who is blind. Make sure that your content is readable without any concept of columns or rows. And if columns and rows are essential then use a `table` but read about marking up a table to make it accessible to a text-reader.

Answer (score 1):

Use the css `dispay` property for this:

```
`table`               Let the element behave like a <table> element 
`table-caption`       Let the element behave like a <caption> element
`table-column-group`  Let the element behave like a <colgroup> element  
`table-header-group`  Let the element behave like a <thead> element 
`table-footer-group`  Let the element behave like a <tfoot> element 
`table-row-group`     Let the element behave like a <tbody> element 
`table-cell`          Let the element behave like a <td> element    
`table-column`        Let the element behave like a <col> element   
`table-row`           Let the element behave like a <tr> element
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use a div and the corresponding css to generate a table layout.
For example

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the css, it would be something like

```
.table { display: table; }
.row { display: table-row; }
.cell { display: table-cell; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap to make it possible.You can also get a really awesome looking page with it.apply bootstrap classes to the div elements.search about bootstrap.it s simple and nowadays all webdevelopers use it in company.The benefit is you can get really awesome looking page with simple code in any way u need.It s simple just add bootstrap files to your project and use the css classes it provides.you can create tables as u wish with div.

Answer (score 0):

The therme you are looking for is **[Tableless layout](http://www.w3.org/2002/03/csslayout-howto)** or **[css grid](http://chrismaxwell.com/tableless/grid.html)**

if you google it you will find many implementations but here is one :

### HTML

```
<div id="table">
    <p><span class="col1">&nbsp;</span><span class="col2">&nbsp;</span><span class="col3">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p><span class="col1">&nbsp;</span><span class="col2">&nbsp;</span><span class="col3">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p><span class="col1">&nbsp;</span><span class="col2">&nbsp;</span><span class="col3">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p><span class="col1">&nbsp;</span><span class="col2">&nbsp;</span><span class="col3">&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#table {
    width: 470px;
    border-top: 4px solid #e3e7e7;
    }

#table p {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    }

#table span {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #e3e7e7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e7e7;
    }

#table span.col1 {
    width: 110px;
    }

#table span.col2 {
    width: 186px;
    }

#table span.col3 {
    width: 110px;
    border-right: 1px solid #e3e7e7;
    }
```

### Result

[image]